# How to display magento 2 swatches on category page

Tags: magento2.3

How to move magento 2 swatches on category page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the Magento2 default itself has the functionality to show the color swatches on the category page. If you are setting up the attribute properly. Below you can find the link to cross-check the setup.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-swatches-in-magento-2.html

And don't forget to setup attribute configure 'Storefront Properties' -> 'Used in Product Listing' as true.

In some cases, if you are looking to change the rendering position check the below codes, which will help you.

```
<?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
```

Wherever you want you can update in list.phtml.

Hope this will help you to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi how do I align the color swatches to the center? All my swatches are flushed to the left now in the category page?